# linux: getting the pages shared between parent and forked child

Tags: linux, memory-management

From what I understand Linux does not copy all the parent process memory to a separate page for the child process, it does a copy-on-write. Till either process modifies (writes) some memory location in the mapped (shared) page, we will have the child and the parent virtual address spaces mapped to the same physical memory location (same physical page).

I would like to know if there is a tool available which shows me the physical memory page #'s being shared by the processes. Or any tool which gives the virtual address -> physical address mapping. so that I can actually look at the physical address and check if the processes are being mapped to the same physical memory.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like an XY question. Could you explain why you want to know if a page is mapped to a child process or not?

Comment: You would need to look at the paging tables stored within the kernel from the looks of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specialized tool available, but every information needed should already be exported via the `/proc` filesystem.

The special use case given in your question is even explicitly mentioned in the relevant documentation. (either `linux-src-directory/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt` or online https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt):

> The general procedure for using pagemap to find out about a process'
>   memory usage goes like this:
>
> 1. Read /proc/pid/maps to determine which parts of the memory space are
>      mapped to what.
> 2. Select the maps you are interested in -- all of them, or a particular
>      library, or the stack or the heap, etc.
> 3. Open /proc/pid/pagemap and seek to the pages you would like to examine.
> 4. Read a u64 for each page from pagemap.
> 5. Open /proc/kpagecount and/or /proc/kpageflags.  For each PFN you just
>      read, seek to that entry in the file, and read the data you want.
>
> For example, to find the "unique set size" (USS), which is the amount
>   of memory that a process is using that is not shared with any other
>   process, you can go through every map in the process, find the PFNs,
>   look those up in kpagecount, and tally up the number of pages that are
>   only referenced once.